# Help with multirow table

Tags: tables, multirow, wrap

I am trying to wrap text in the multirow column (1st one) and only have the vertical lines inside the table if that makes sense.

Can anyone help me? `

```
\begin{table*}[!htbp]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{tabular}{|c| p{2cm}|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{3-6}
&&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Gravité du Dommage G1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Gravité du Dommage G2}}\\ 
\cline{3-6}
&&\textbf{Fréquence F1} & \textbf{Fréquence F2} & \textbf{Fréquence F1} & \textbf{Fréquence F2}\\
\hline
\multirow{ 2}{*}{\textbf{Probabilité Occurence O1}}&\textbf{Possibilité Evitement P1}&&&&\\
\cline{2-6}
&\textbf{Possibilité Evitement P2}&&&&\\
\hline
\multirow{ 2}{*}{\textbf{Probabilité Occurence O2}}&\textbf{Possibilité Evitement P1}&&&&\\
\cline{2-6}
&\textbf{Possibilité Evitement P2}&&&&\\
\hline
\multirow{ 2}{*}{\textbf{Probabilité Occurence O3}}&\textbf{Possibilité Evitement P1}&&&&\\
\cline{2-6}
&\textbf{Possibilité Evitement P2}&&&&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you asking for?

[image]

Since you didn't provide any information about your document and used packages, I 
in above MWE add only necessary one:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{array,makecell,multirow}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}

    \usepackage[margin=25mm,showframe]{geometry}
    \newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}l| >{\bfseries}p{2cm}|c|c|c|c|}
    \cline{3-6}
\mc{}
        &   \mc{Gravité du Dommage G1}
            &   \mc{Gravité du Dommage G2}                  \\
    \cline{3-6}
\mc{}
        &   \thead{Fréquence F1} & \thead{Fréquence F2}
            &   \thead{Fréquence F1} & \thead{Fréquence F2} \\
    \hline
\multirowcell{5}{Probabilité\\ Occurence O1}
    &   Possibilité Evitement P1
        &&&&   \\
    \cline{2-6}
    &   Possibilité Evitement P2
        &&&&\\
    \hline
\multirowcell{5}{Probabilité\\ Occurence O2}
    &   Possibilité Evitement P1
        &&&&\\
    \cline{2-6}
    &   Possibilité Evitement P2
        &&&&\\
    \hline
\multirowcell{5}{Probabilité\\ Occurence O3}
    &   Possibilité Evitement P1
        &&&&\\
    \cline{2-6}
    &   Possibilité Evitement P2
        &&&&\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with makecell, which allows for line breaks in cells and common formatting.
I also propose a nicer-looking table, without vertical rules, using the `booktabs` package:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{array, caption}
    \usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
    \usepackage{cellspace}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{lc}

    \begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!htbp]
  \centering\footnotesize
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
  %\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|c|c|c|}
    \cline{3-6}
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Gravité du Dommage G1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Gravité du Dommage G2}}\\
    \cline{3-6}
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}&\textbf{Fréquence F1} & \textbf{Fréquence F2} & \textbf{Fréquence F1} & \textbf{Fréquence F2}\\
    \hline
    \multirowthead{3}{Probabilité & \\ Occurrence O1}&\thead[lc]{Possibilité\\ Évitement P1}&&&&\\
    \cline{2-6}
                                   & \thead[lc]{Possibilité \\ Évitement P2}&&&&\\
    \hline
    \multirowthead{3}{Probabilité & \\ Occurrence O2}&\thead[lc]{Possibilité\\ Évitement P1}&&&&\\
    \cline{2-6}
                                   & \thead{Possibilité \\ Évitement P2}&&&&\\
    \hline
    \multirowthead{3}{Probabilité & \\ Occurrence O3}&\thead[lc]{Possibilité\\ Évitement P1}&&&&\\
    \cline{2-6}
                                   & \thead{Possibilité \\ Évitement P2}&&&&\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\vskip1cm
\begin{table*}[!htbp]
  \centering\footnotesize
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}ll*{4}{c}}
    \toprule
    & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Gravité du Dommage G1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Gravité du Dommage G2}}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}
                                   & \\
    \midrule
    \multirowthead{3}{Probabilité & \\ Occurrence O1}&\thead[lc]{Possibilité\\ Évitement P1}&&&&\\
    \addlinespace
                                   & \thead[lc]{Possibilité \\ Évitement P2}&&&&\\
    \midrule
    \multirowthead{3}{Probabilité & \\ Occurrence O2}&\thead[lc]{Possibilité\\ Évitement P1}&&&&\\
    \addlinespace
                                   & \thead{Possibilité \\ Évitement P2}&&&&\\
    \midrule
    \multirowthead{3}{Probabilité & \\ Occurrence O3}&\thead[lc]{Possibilité\\ Évitement P1}&&&&\\
    \addlinespace
                                   & \thead{Possibilité \\ Évitement P2}&&&&\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]