# how to make this Table with multiple rows

Tags: tables

Hi all how i could make this table in latex?? i tried but no luck
[image]

here is the code i try:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\tablelasttail{}
\begin{supertabular}{m{26.7mm}m{50.53mm}|m{41.66mm}|m{49.01mm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|m{26.7mm}|}{{\selectlanguage{english} Main Topic}} &
{\selectlanguage{english} Topic} &
{\selectlanguage{english} Sub Topic} &
{\selectlanguage{english} Publication}\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|m{26.7mm}|}{{\selectlanguage{english} A}} &
{\selectlanguage{english} A1} &
~
 &
{\selectlanguage{english} 1}\\\hline
 &
{\selectlanguage{english} A2} &
~
 &
{\selectlanguage{english} 2}\\\hhline{~---}
 &
 &
 &
{\selectlanguage{english} 3}\\\hhline{~~~-}
 &
 &
 &
{\selectlanguage{english} 4}\\\hhline{~~~-}
 &
{\selectlanguage{english} A3} &
{\selectlanguage{english} E1} &
{\selectlanguage{english} 5}\\\hhline{~---}
 &
 &
 &
{\selectlanguage{english} 6}\\\hhline{~~~-}
 &
 &
 &
{\selectlanguage{english} 7}\\\hhline{~~~-}
 &
 &
 &
{\selectlanguage{english} 8}\\\hhline{~~~-}
 &
 &
{\selectlanguage{english} E2} &
{\selectlanguage{english} 9}\\\hhline{~~--}
 &
 &
 &
{\selectlanguage{english} 10}\\\hhline{~~~-}
 &
 &
{\selectlanguage{english} E3} &
{\selectlanguage{english} 11}\\\hhline{~~--}
 &
 &
 &
{\selectlanguage{english} 12}\\\hhline{~~~-}
\multicolumn{1}{|m{26.7mm}|}{{\selectlanguage{english} B}} &
{\selectlanguage{english} B1} &
~
 &
{\selectlanguage{english} 13}\\\hline
 &
{\selectlanguage{english} B2} &
~
 &
{\selectlanguage{english} 14}\\\hhline{~---}
\end{supertabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us what you have tried. You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). A LaTeX MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The example should compile.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289940/help-with-multirow-table

Comment: @Andrew - I've re-opened this posting as I don't think it's a duplicate of [Help with multirow table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/289940/5001). For instance, the earlier posting did *not* lend itself at all to an application of `\multirow` instructions -- despite the presence of the word "multirow" in the posting's title... In contrast, the current posting would be much more tedious to handle without the `multirow` package.

Comment: @Mico I didn't vote or suggest to close! I just said it was related:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Use `\multirow` statements for the material that should span 2, 3, 4, 8, or 12 rows.
- Use `\cline` instructions, as they're easier to parse than the `\hhline` directives.
- Please get rid of all `\selectlanguage{english}` directives. If you really must, just provide a single `\selectlanguage{english}` directive immediately before `\begin{tabularx}...`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  % set page parameters
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color,array,supertabular}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\tablelasttail{}
\begin{supertabular}{|l|p{40mm}|p{40mm}|p{45mm}|}
\hline
Main Topic & Topic & Sub Topic & Publication\\
\hline
\multirow{12}{*}{A} & A1 & & 1 \\
\cline{2-4}
 & \multirow{3}{*}{A2} & & 2 \\
\cline{4-4}
 & & & 3 \\
\cline{4-4}
 & & & 4 \\
\cline{2-4}
 & \multirow{8}{*}{A3} & \multirow{4}{*}{E1}& 5 \\
 \cline{4-4}
 & & & 6 \\
\cline{4-4}
 & & & 7 \\
\cline{4-4}
 & & & 8 \\
\cline{3-4}
 & & \multirow{2}{*}{E2}& 9 \\
\cline{4-4}
 & & & 10 \\
\cline{3-4}
 & & \multirow{2}{*}{E3}& 11 \\
\cline{4-4}
 & & & 12\\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{B} & B1 & & 13\\
\cline{2-4}
 & B2 & & 14 \\
\hline
\end{supertabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```